# Loop over directories one level deep and execute script with directory name as argument in bash in that directory

Tags: linux, bash, loops, subdirectory

I have a batch script which I want to use to run on all directories at a specific level. It calls a script(***recon1.sh***) which takes directory name as an argument and stores result folders in each sub-directory.
What I want is that when *pathway_name* is specified from the commandline(**bash batch_recon1.sh pathway_X**), it ***cd*** into each protein folder(protein_A,protein_B, ....protein_Z) and execute recon1.sh and do this for all proteins under the pathway folder. Currently, it ends after one protein(protein_***A***) doesn't start for protein_***B*** and others. How can I fix this? I have tried with simpler script which loops over sub-folders only one level deep and write file_names in that directory to text file, which works perfectly fine, but for some reason this code(batch_recon1.sh for recon1.sh) isn't working. Can someone help?

folder structure:

[***software folder***]

```
${HOME}/ProjName/software/batch_recon1.sh

${HOME}/ProjName/software/recon1.sh
```

[***Project folder***]

```
${HOME}/ProjName/pathways/Pathway_X/protein_A/

${HOME}/ProjName/pathways/Pathway_X/protein_A/protein_A_id
${HOME}/ProjName/pathways/Pathway_X/protein_A/protein_A_searchRes
${HOME}/ProjName/pathways/Pathway_X/protein_A/protein_A_alignment

${HOME}/ProjName/pathways/Pathway_X/protein_B/

${HOME}/ProjName/pathways/Pathway_X/protein_B/protein_B_id
${HOME}/ProjName/pathways/Pathway_X/protein_B/protein_B_searchRes
${HOME}/ProjName/pathways/Pathway_X/protein_B/protein_B_alignment
```

recon1.sh takes protein_name as arg
(e.g. recon1.sh protein_A)

so ${dirname} should be  (i.e.) "protein_A" not full path to protein folder.

used as (from command line) ***bash batch_recon1.sh Pathway_X***

code for ***batch_recon1.sh***:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
        
    set -e
    current_path=$(pwd)
    
    pathway_name=$1
    path_to_folder=${HOME}/ProjName/pathways/${pathway_name}
    path_to_software_folder=${HOME}/ProjName/software

    cd ${path_to_folder}
    echo '----running batch_reconcile1.sh on pathway:'$@
        
        


    for fol in "${path_to_folder}"/*/; do
      [ -d "${fol}" ] || continue ## if not a directory skip
      dirname="$(basename "${fol}")"
      (cd "${fol}" && bash ${path_to_software_folder}/recon1.sh ${dirname} )
      cd ..
    done
```

Comment: `(cd "${fol}" && ...)` is executed in a subshell. Do not `cd ..` after that. Note: better double-quote all parameter expansions (e.g. `pathway_name="$1"`). Note: there is no need to `bash ${path_to_software_folder}/recon1.sh ${dirname}`. Simply `"${path_to_software_folder}/recon1.sh" "${dirname}"`.

Comment: thanks @RenaudPacalet ! For some reason, it keeps saying "Permission Denied". I'm using Ubuntu 18 LTS via ssh from Mac.

Comment: Is `${HOME}/ProjName/software/recon1.sh$` executable? If not try `chmod +x ${HOME}/ProjName/software/recon1.sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is probably exiting early because `recon1.sh` is failing, and you have `set -e` (exit if a command fails).

It's probably failing due to `cd ..` which should not be there.

It may be also be better to keep attempting `recon1.sh` on *all* proteins, even if one fails (that's up to you).

Replace

```
(cd "${fol}" && bash ${path_to_software_folder}/recon1.sh ${dirname} )
cd ..
```

With:

```
cd "${fol}" || continue
bash ${path_to_software_folder}/recon1.sh "${dirname}" || echo "recon1.sh failed for ${dirname}" >&2
```

The working directory gets set correctly. If `recon1.sh` still fails for any reason, an error is printed, but the script won't exit, and the next protein is attempted.

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for.(minor: for some reason, it prints "recon1.sh failed for protein_name" even when it has not failed.) It's working now! Thanks @dan

Comment: The error will only be printed if `recon1.sh` returns non zero (failure). A shell script returns with the status of the last command executed (unless `exit <number>` is called), so some command in `recon1.sh` is definitely failing. It may be just doing so after it's done what you need it to do (or at least some). You should look at `recon1.sh`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out @dan. indeed, in the log there is a "No such file or directory" error. (It seems to have given output alright nonetheless (probably because of an older version of file called from recon1.sh existed )).

Comment: @007 No worries. Perhaps a better message might be `an error occurred in recon1.sh for ${dirname}`. Or you could just remove this part altogether (including `||`). If the answer worked for you, you can accept it (if you want). Thanks.